# Como mudar a versão do PHP em que o Composer é executado no Windows?

Tags: php, composer, xampp, terminal

Tenho o PHP 8 instalado e rodando no Xampp. Alterei as configurações para rodar a versão do php 7.1 em outra porta. Tudo certo até aí.
Mas na hora de rodar o composer no terminal diz que a versão do PHP é a 8 e não é compatível com meu sistema feito em PHP 7.1.
Como faço pra alterar a versão do PHP no terminal?
Quando executo > php -v, aparece a versão 8.0 eu preciso alterar para 7.1.
Já tem uma resposta aqui no fórum sobre isso, mas é para Linux, não encontrei nada para Windows.

Comment: Já tentou usando os paths completos? `C:\path_para_php7.1\php7.1.exe C:\path_para_composer\composer -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

- Renomeei as pastas c:\xampp\apache e c:\xampp\php para c:\xampp\apache8 e c:\xampp\php8, respectivamente.
- Baixei o xampp com php 7.1, que eu precisava
- Copiei as pastas apache e php da versão baixada pro lugar das anteriores c:\xampp\apache e c:\xampp\php
- Reiniciei os serviços do xamp.

E pronto!

Foi a forma mais simples que encontrei.

Agora, quando preciso mudar de versão, renomeio a pasta que está sendo usada e substituo pelas pastas da versão que preciso.

Answer (score -3):

Reinstale o composer, e na hora de selecionar a versão coloque a versão que deseja e marque a opção de adicionar ao PATH do Windows, logo após abra novamente o projeto.

Comment: Eu preciso alterar a versão do PHP no terminal do Windows, desculpe, mas não entendi como isso vai ajudar.

Comment: Isso vai fazer o que você precisa, quando eu preciso mudar a versão faço isso.